# How to fix serial communication in Arduino and Python with Azure platform to Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, azure, arduino, anaconda

I have problem for communication serial (USB) in my Arduino code. I am using platform azure python, Windown10

I already checked the COM ports

```
ser = serial.Serial( "COM5", 9600) 
i=0

while i<180:
ser.write(str(chr(116)))


#t = raw_input("teste")
#print type(teste)
#ser.println((str(chr(1160))))
#time.sleep(1000)
print (ser.readline())
```

But I receive this error:

> Module 'serial' has no 'Serial' member; maybe 'serial'?